# How do I properly send a PDF file through PHP?

Tags: php, pdf, http-headers, mime-types

I am trying to send a PDF file. Here is the code that is executing:

```
$file_path = '/path/to/file/filename.pdf'
$file_name = 'filename.pdf'

header("X-Sendfile: $file_path");
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='$filename'");
readfile($file_path):
```

whenever I download the file directly, it is fine. however when I try to download the file via this script, a file downloads that cannot be opened. my pdf reader tells me it cannot open a file of type 'text/plain'. I also tried setting the `Content-type` to `application/pdf` , but I get the same errors. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: That's odd, I was working on a similar script the other night and `header('Content-type: application/pdf');` worked for me with `readfile`. Are you sure the path is correct?

Comment: As a side note, you probably want to use `$file_name` in your header line, not `$filename` which doesn't exist in your snippet?

Comment: `header(...; filename='$file_name'");` <--note the `_`.

Comment: Also, might be a good idea to make sure you have permissions to the file, and that it does exist using `is_readable`, just a tip, hope it helps!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
$file = '/path/to/file/filename.pdf';
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'. basename($file) . '"');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
```

Using [readfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) also eliminates any memory issues you might encounter.

Answer (score 1):

try the code below.

```
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");

$file = "filename.pdf";
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . urlencode($file));   
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");            
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
flush(); // this doesn't really matter.
$fp = fopen($file, "r");
while (!feof($fp))
{
    echo fread($fp, 65536);
    flush(); // this is essential for large downloads
} 
fclose($fp)
```

If the above one does not help you try the below

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . urlencode(basename($file)));
// header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
exit;
```

Don't for get to set the file path `$file_path` as required.

Comment: Why three `Content-Type` headers?

Comment: Note that `flush()` doesn't do anything if PHP is running as a CGI.

Comment: i would'nt force the download nor even stream data with PHP - this language is highly unreliable in regards of data-types, you are likely to run into errors and problems with this. If you want to provide downloads just setup your webserver accordingly - thats what webservers are made for, they will guarantee to every possible extent an unmodified & correct delivery.
btw : i got no problem with PHP, i just know about its edges, strengths and weaknesses. Dont use PHP if you want to keep proprietary data intact

Comment: above code did the work for me & helped me to get the job done, so I thought it would work for other people too.

Comment: Why did my comment get removed? "Highly unreliable": only if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: because you were being offensive - trolling isnt wanted around here.
Furthermore : yes indeed, but most people find it way too hard to use PHP in a way which ensures atomic data-integrity - thats actually a complex task with this scripting-language. The other 1% who think PHP raises no problems with complex data-structures ... well - they dont know much about software development yet.
PHP has many uses, many strengths - but also quite a few weaknesses; like data-types and data integrity.  

Its not easy to ensure integrity - even with languages like C and PHP isnt different.

Comment: Sorry if I came across as offensive, what I find offensive is someone who completely derides a language when in reality they don't take the time to understand or learn it.